# Given two datetimes A and B alongside their difference A - B, why is the sum of B and the difference not equal to A during a leap-year?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timedelta, python-datetime, leap-year

Below is some sample code used to create an example.

```
import datetime

a1 = datetime.datetime(1999, 3, 1, 2)
a2 = datetime.datetime(1999, 2, 28, 0)
b1 = datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 1, 2)
b2 = datetime.datetime(2000, 2, 28, 0)

res_a = a1 - a2 # not a leap-year
res_b = b1 - b2 # is a leap-year

print("\n>> TIME DIFFERENCE\n   ... {} minus {}\n   ... {}\n".format(a1, a2, res_a))
print(">> FUTURE TIME\n   ... {} + {}\n   ... {}\n".format(a1, res_a, a1+res_a))
print(">> TIME DIFFERENCE\n   ... {} minus {}\n   ... {}\n".format(b1, b2, res_b))
print(">> FUTURE TIME\n   ... {} + {}\n   ... {}\n".format(b1, res_b, b1+res_b))
print(">> FUTURE TIME\n   ... {} + {}\n   ... {}\n".format(a2, res_b, a2+res_b))
```

Running the code above produces the following output.

```
>> TIME DIFFERENCE
   ... 1999-03-01 02:00:00 minus 1999-02-28 00:00:00
   ... 1 day, 2:00:00

>> FUTURE TIME
   ... 1999-03-01 02:00:00 + 1 day, 2:00:00
   ... 1999-03-02 04:00:00

# *****
>> TIME DIFFERENCE
   ... 2000-03-01 02:00:00 minus 2000-02-28 00:00:00
   ... 2 days, 2:00:00

>> FUTURE TIME
   ... 2000-03-01 02:00:00 + 2 days, 2:00:00
   ... 2000-03-03 04:00:00

# *****
>> FUTURE TIME
   ... 1999-02-28 00:00:00 + 2 days, 2:00:00
   ... 1999-03-02 02:00:00
```

It makes sense that there is an extra day that is accounted for when checking for the time elapsed between Feb 28 and March 1 during a leap-year (first `*****`). But when adding this time difference to the original day (say Feb 28), the output is one day added to the original day (second `*****`).

For my purpose, I am reading time-series data and creating a dataset using the number of elapsed hours alongside corresponding datetimes. Given the behaviour of the code, I'm not quite sure how to proceed. Is this a bug in the module or is this something related to the proper way of reading a calendar?

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly mistake.

The last `print` statement should read as

```
print(">> FUTURE TIME\n   ... {} + {}\n   ... {}\n".format(b2, res_b, b2+res_b))
```

to produce the following output

```
>> FUTURE TIME
   ... 2000-02-28 00:00:00 + 2 days, 2:00:00
   ... 2000-03-01 02:00:00
```